# Debugging stops on setting value at runtime

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am changing a variable's value at run-time while debugging. This, I am doing under the Variable section at bottom of `Android Studio`.

[image]

However, when I set the value with the new `HTML` text, the debugging suddenly stops/ disconnects.
Please correct me.

Comment: and by stops you mean disconnects ?

Comment: @Blackbelt : Correct.

Comment: it sounds like a bug. Which version are you using ?

Comment: @Blackbelt : Android Studio 1.1.0